# How to find all ELB that are using specific subnet in AWS vis CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, command-line-interface, elastic-load-balancer

We are running low on IP addresses in a specific subnet in AWS.  I was able to find all ec2 instances using IP address from this specific subnet.  Now I am trying to find all Elastic Load Balancers using this subnet via the AWS CLI.

I know that I can run the following to find all ELB on a specific VPC:

aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?VPCId==`vpc-12345678`]|[].LoadBalancerName'

I think the issue with subnets is you can have multiple subnets.  So it is a list instead of just one value like VPCId.

I tried the following:

aws --region us-east-1 elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?Subnets==`subnet-1234546`]|[].LoadBalancerName'

But it came back with nothing even though I can see from previous search that some ELB do have the specific subnet I am looking for.  I think it is due to it being a list of subnets but I'm unsure how how to search for it.

Any ideas?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Will this work for you?

```
aws elb describe-load-balancers --query 'LoadBalancerDescriptions[?contains(Subnets, `subnet-1234546`)==`true`].LoadBalancerName' --output text
```

Comment: Yes, this was perfect! Thank you!